# How do I manually install the man pages for Java JDK system-wide?

Tags: installation, manpage

I'm installing the Java JDK manually, by downloading the JDK tar archive from java.com, extracting it into `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32` (also the OpenJDK installation location via apt), and using *[update-alternatives](https://github.com/byrongibson/scripts/blob/master/install/java/oracle-jdk1.6.0_32-server-allslave.sh)* to add all the java binaries to `/usr/bin`.

I'd also like to the install the Java man pages system-wide in `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/man/man1`, preferably using that same update-alternatives script, but not sure how.

I've tried soft linking `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/man/man1` as `/usr/share/man/man.java`, but no luck, `man java` doesn't work.  Running `man --update` and `mandb` don't seem to do anything.

Anyone know how to manually install man packages?

Comment: Found one solution.  Soft link `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/man/man1` as `/usr/share/man/man10` (10 is next in the list, there is already `/usr/share/man/man1-man9`).  Is that the cannonical way of manually installing man pages, or is there something else?  Not sure what the naming convention is for /usr/share/man; why does `man10` work but not `man.java`?

Comment: Another observation, linking as `/usr/share/man/man20` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, not sure if this is the canonical way though:

Soft link `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/man/man1` as `/usr/share/man/man10` (10 is next in the list, there is already `/usr/share/man/man1-man9`).

Not sure what the naming convention is for `/usr/share/man`; why does man10 work but not man.java or man20?  Linking as `/usr/share/man/man20` doesn't work either.

See [update-alternatives script](https://github.com/byrongibson/scripts/blob/master/install/java/oracle-jdk1.6.0_32-server-allslave.sh) for full example (last line for man page link).

Answer (score 2):

[Download the DOC from here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/default-jdk-doc/download) and open with the Software center or with this command from terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i <path to file_name>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want the OpenJDK docs.  I'm required to use Oracle JDK for compatibility reasons, and want the corresponding Oracle JDK docs, which don't have a deb package version.